# NOSQL (RavenDB) Query from a folder on C: Drive

Tags: c#, nosql, ravendb

I have a database on the C drive and I need to query from it to get all of the names of restaurants. I'm new to RavenDB and can't seem to find any documentation on how to query from a folder that sits on the C drive of the computer. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the database was created in drive C at creation time, then RavenDB knows where it is located.
Run your RavenDB server.
Specify your localhost URL when initializing the store:

```
  var store = new DocumentStore
            {
                Urls = new[] {"http://127.0.0.1:8080"},
                Database = "your-database-name"
            };

  store.Initialize();
```

After that, you just query your database.

If you manually moved the database from its original created location to some other folder then you couldn't query.
You can [Export](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/csharp/studio/database/tasks/export-database) the database and [Import](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/csharp/studio/database/tasks/import-data/import-data-file) it to a new database in a new location.

Answer (score 3):

You can point RavenDB server to a specific data directory - in this way you can load your database and query it.
Simply edit **settings.json** in the folder where you find **Raven.Server.exe** and write the desired data folder in **DataDir** property. In the end, your settings file would look similar to this:

```json
{
  "DataDir": "D:\\foo\\bar",
 /* other settings... */
}
```

Note, if you run RavenDB in Docker, you can adjust the configuration using environment variables. (more about this here: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/start/installation/running-in-docker-container)